# How can I change my assigned user role in WordPress 3.5.1?

Tags: plugin-development, users, user-roles

My current user role is "Administrator". I'd like to change my role to "Editor" (through out database field).

I read [Database_Description](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description), but it did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Either use [`wp_update_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user)

```
wp_update_user(
    array (
        'ID' => 1, // replace by your user ID
        'role' => 'editor'
    )
) ;
```

or the [`set_role`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User#set_role.28.24role.29) method of the [`WP_User`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) class.

```
$you = new WP_User( 1 ); // again, replace parameter by your user ID
$you->set_role( 'editor' );
```

Comment: Final answer got it. Table of wp_usermeta ->a:1:{s:6:"editor";s:1:"1";} insted of a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";} field. 'S' for number of character in string [Prove](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/changing-user-roles)

Comment: [sarcasm on]Yes, that's much better than using an API.[/sarcasm off]